# Where can I find correlation between US News ranking and IPEDS database?

Tags: ranking

I have been building a search tool for colleges and universities in US. I could find most of the data from the IPEDS database. Now I am trying to relate the colleges with US News ranking. I'm trying to find any source of data which could give me ranking of colleges with their UNITID/college name .
Any clues on how to get the rankings data along with UNITID ?

Comment: What is IPEDS?  What is UNITID?

Comment: database of colleges from government nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/. UNITID is the unique identification of each college

Comment: I can't answer your question, though I like it.  But I'm wondering if it is possible and easy to do name matching from US News ranking (assuming you can find it in electronic form) with the college names in IPEDS data base.

Comment: I checked with IPEDS and they do not have any such co relation with them. They will rank based on completion data, enrollments or any other variable they have data for, but not for US news or financial times ranking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uploaded a file to wikisend (free and no sign-up file hosting service) with the correlation.

[US News and IPEDS ID](http://wikisend.com/download/470842/usnwr_unitid.txt)

Actually pastebin never expires so here's a link to it on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/FNEaJ1vC

Comment: Very nice. And this is latest data. Not sure how the national university ranking is different from Engineering and MBA program ranking

Answer (score 3):

The above source appears to be limited in years.

I've found this current source:

https://andyreiter.com/datasets/

Contains IPEDS ids and USNews & Report rankings up through 2022.

Comment: Where is the reference with IPEDS? That was one of the important co-relation? Can this dataset be used as a reference on any website? Asking this because PDF mentions "not for publication"